# JavaScript library for plotting maps

Tags: javascript, charts, maps

I am building dashboard for sales company and I need to plot map of India on it. It should highlight different states on the map according to the sales in that area. Please suggest suitable JS library that can be helpful.

Comment: This question is highly opinion-based. Have you tried OpenStreetMaps or Google Maps?

Comment: Google maps can not show me detailed views for states within India, and I need that.

Answer (score 3):

Use amCharts for Dynamically plotting maps.

It will allow to add interactive charts and maps using amCharts libraries

[Demo](http://www.amcharts.com/demos/drill-down-map/)

[www.amCharts.com](http://www.amcharts.com/)

Comment: I need to be able to drilldown to state level, this map is providing drill down to country level only.

Comment: No, you can make it to work for states also For Eg: http://www.amcharts.com/visited_states/

Answer (score 2):

Choosing a suitable JS library for this project will depend on finding one that allows you to plot your sales data geographically. You will likely chose from a few maps options:

- GIS maps (probably more complex than what is required for your needs)
- Maps which are simply images that represent shapes similar to your regions (ie India and states in India)
- Maps which drawn with actual latitude and longitude data (seems like the best fit for you)

The benefit of latitude and longitude data maps is the ability to plot data accurately based on geographical information. I personally have experience with ZingChart, which is a JavaScript library that provide latitude and longitude maps (with India as a country, and a drill-down level to India states).

Here is a demo of how it looks -- http://zingchart.com/playground/run/54077e9d8cd24

And here is an example of the type of map highlighting I think you want to do -- http://www.zingchart.com/gallery/?ID=25586

If you need the next level of states in India, the folks at ZingChart could probably accommodate that request, too. As a member of the team I'm happy to help so please reach out if you have additional questions.

Answer (score 0):

[JSMaps](https://jsmaps.io/) is another option which is an open-source project with an MIT [license](https://jsmaps.io/license/)

[India Map](https://jsmaps.io/asia/javascript-map-of-india/)

Answer (score -1):

highcharts.com is one solution for the service you are looking for.

Here is an implementation example over india with population, which can be easily replaced with sales in that area.

The full example can be found in the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.11.0/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/mapdata/countries/in/in-all)

```
// Initiate the chart
$('#container').highcharts('Map', {
    title : {
        text : 'Highmaps basic demo'
    },
    subtitle : {
        text : 'Source map: <a href="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/in/in-all.js">India</a>'
    },
    mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        buttonOptions: {
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
    },
    colorAxis: {
        min: 0
    },
    series : [{
        data : data,
        mapData: Highcharts.maps['countries/in/in-all'],
        joinBy: 'hc-key',
        name: 'Random data',
        states: {
            hover: {
                color: '#BADA55'
            }
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{point.name}'
        }
    }]
});
```